# NES chips usage

Tags: emulation, nes

I am curently studying NES architecture to create a NES emulator. While looking up the NES motherboard schematics (https://console5.com/wiki/Nintendo_NES-001), some of the chips usage are not clear to me:

- U2: 74LS373
- U3: 74LS139
- U7, U8: 74368
- U9: 74HCU04

Comment: These are standard [74-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400-series_integrated_circuits), [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic) logic chips. For a useful answer, it might be helpful if you could be more specific about what you want to know.

Comment: Data sheets can be found just by typing the chip identifiers into Google (I tried and succeeded).

Comment: @another-dave Actually, an easier way to find the data sheets is to use Wikipedia's [list of 7400 series integrated circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits), which provides brief descriptions of all of them and direct links to data sheets.

Comment: 74x373 is a register, x139 a decoder and x04 six inverters.

Comment: I looked into the data sheets, but it is easier to understand them in context, hence my question

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may also find useful [this other schematic](https://nesdev.com/Ntd_8bit.jpg), which I find
easier to read, though some of the design details differ. It's from
the [NesDev wiki](http://wiki.nesdev.com/w/index.php/Nesdev) which is a fount of useful technical
information about older Nintendo consoles.

All of the chips you mention are low-level interface logic, and
probably not important for your emulation. You'll need to do the same
things that those chips help to do, but almost certainly in different
ways.

The **[74LS373](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls373.pdf)** is an 8-bit latch. When the `ALE` ("address latch
enable") line of the PPU is high, the latch reads the data from
`AD0-7` and passes it through to `A0-7` on the RAM chip. When `ALE`
goes low it "freezes" the data on its outputs and ignores any changes
to its inputs, basically "capturing" the low 8 bits of the address
being sent to the RAM.

This is necessary because the `AD0-7` outputs from the PPU are
connected not only to A0-A7 of the RAM (though the latch), but also
`D0-7` of the RAM. (This multiplexing saves pins.) This is very hard
to see due to blurred text on the schematic you linked, but much more
clear in the one I linked above. So here's what a read cycle looks
like:

1. The PPU  deasserts `R̅D̅`, generates an address on `AD0-7` and
   asserts `ALE`.
2. Because `R̅D̅` is not asserted, the RAM disables its `D0-7` I/O pins
   so that they will have no effect on the bus. Because `ALE` is
   asserted, the '373 reads its input pins and passes the address on
   `AD0-7` through to the `A0-7` pins on the RAM.
3. The PPU deasserts `ALE`. This causes the '347 to start ignoring its
   inputs, and thus any data on `AD0-7`, and maintain the old value on
   its outputs, holding the address on RAM pins `A0-7`.
4. The PPU asserts `R̅D̅`, enabling the RAM data outputs `D0-7`, and it
   can now read those data on pins `AD0-7`.

The **[74LS139](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls139a.pdf)** is a decoder used for address decoding. Basically,
it's a pair of units that take a two bit binary number as input to the
A and B pins, and drive low one of Y0, Y1, Y2 or Y3 depending on what
the input number is. (Or it may leave all of the outputs high if the
chip is not selected.) Here's the function table (`G̅` is the select
pin, which must be low to enable output):

```
    G̅  A  B      Y0 Y1 Y2 Y3
    0  0  0   →   0  1  1  1
    0  1  0   →   1  0  1  1
    0  0  1   →   1  1  0  1
    0  1  1   →   1  1  1  0
    1  x  x   →   1  1  1  1
```

In this particular case it's generating the enable signal for U1, the
2K static RAM. The inputs to the first half are the clock (φ2) and
A15; if these are 1 and 0 respectively, Y1 goes low. (The clock is
used here because the address and data for the memory are valid only
when it's high.) Y1 in turn enables the second two-bit decoder, which
takes A14 and A13 as inputs; if both are low then its Y0 output goes
low, and that enables the RAM.

The effect of this is that accessing any address between $8000 and
$AFFF will enable the RAM.

The **[74368](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls366a.pdf)** is an inverting tri-state buffer, which has three
functions that can be used alone or in combination: 1) inverting the
signal going through it (changing low to high and high to low), 2)
buffering signals so that something on the other side is driven with
enough power, and 3) connecting or disconnecting whatever's on the
other side of the buffer.

In this case these are used to connect shift registers in the gamepads
to the data bus based on signals from the INP0 and INP1 pins, which
are asserted when you [read the ports $4016 and $4017](http://wiki.nesdev.com/w/index.php?title=Controller_reading).

The **[74HCU04](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/74HCU04.REV0.PDF)** is just a package of six unbuffered inverters,
changing low to high and vice versa. This is not represented as a
single chip on the schematic; the individual inverters are the
triangles with small circles at the point that you see in various
places on the schematic.

Most of these are used at various places where they simply want to
invert a signal, but this particular form of 7404 can also be used as
an amplifier, and it's used as such in the audio output circuit.

Comment: There's a significant difference in 74*HCU*04 inverters from quoted 74ls04 ones: HCUs are single-stage CMOS ones and thus could be used as analog amplifiers, for example in crystal oscillators or audio processing (both options are in NES).

Comment: @lvd Thanks for pointing that out! Looking more closely, it appears to me that, though most of the inverters are used as standard digital inverters (where a 74LS04 would be fine), one is used as part of the audio circuit as an amplifier. I've linked to a data sheet that better describes the 'HCU04 and updated my description.

Comment: I think you mean ports $4016 and $401*7*.

Comment: Thank you - the schematics you linked and your post helped me understand partially the role of 74LS373. However, it is still not clear to me why does NES needs an "address latch". Is this related to https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/trying-to-understand-what-an-address-latch-is-while-emulating-the-nes-ppu ?

Comment: "(I don't know why the chip doesn't just itself maintain the signals on AD0-AD7 via an internal latch.)" -- simply to keep pin count in DIP-40!

Comment: Can you just use regular G instead of the one with the box on top?

Comment: @Filipe No, it's not related to that other question at all; those are completely different latches. I was working out the '373 logic only from the schematic you provided, and due to blurred text I couldn't see that `AD0-7` are actually connected to the address _and_ data pins of the RAM. Re-examining this on the alternative schematic I found made this clear, and I've updated and expanded my answer to explain the need for the latch. Let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: @S.S.Anne The line above the G indicates that the signal is negative logic. If I used the `G` signal instead of the `G̅` (or `/G`) signal there the numbers in that column would be inverted.I just checked, and noticed that SO is breaking this on their mobile site (though it displays fine on Android if you tell your browser to request the desktop site); I'll file a bug report about this.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson It's unlikely that they'll fix it.

Comment: @S.S.Anne I was wrong; this is a bug in Chrome on Android 7.0 (and perhaps other versions); in Opera on Android 7.0 the combining overbar displays just fine on the mobile page. So the workaround is to show the desktop page in Chrome, or use a different browser to view the mobile page.

Comment: So it's either more or less likely that this will be fixed.